# LINQ Include nearby collection (nearby table) and property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, include

I have a class Users with next format:

```
List<Subscriptions> Subscriptions {get;set;}
```

And class Subscriptions contains:

```
SubscriptionType type {get;set;}
```

I'd like to include all of these into User object, something like this:

```
 var _referredUser = ctx.Users
                                .Include(x=>x.Subscriptions.Where(y=>y.Status==true))
                                .ToList()
                                .FirstOrDefault(y => y.Email == _all[i].Referred_email);
```

I can successfully include Subscriptions collection, but I'm not sure how can I go further beyond Subscription collection and include the property SubscriptionType into User object, if it's even possible?

My other question as well is whether I can only include those subscriptions that have status ==true, because user can have multiple records in subscriptions table and only one that is set to true?

I tried something like this, but it throws me an error:

```
.Include(x=>x.Subscriptions.Where(y=>y.Status==true))
```

The error is:

```
 The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
```

Can someone help me out with this LINQ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't filter in an `Include`, I recommend you do this:

```
var email=_all[i].Referred_email;
var _referredUser = ctx.Users.Include(x=>x.Subscriptions.Select(y=>y.SubscriptionType))
                             .FirstOrDefault(y => y.Email == email && y.Subscriptions.Any(y=>y.Status));
```

As the exception said, you must refer a navigation property in the `Include`

Comment: Apparently it can using select operator within the include statement itself.. ?

Comment: Yes, but you can use `Select` to include another inner level referring another navigation property, you can't use a `Where` inside to filter

Comment: Octavio, how could I include here the SubscriptionType as well ?

Comment: Is it a navigation property in your model?

Comment: OctavioCCL, yes

Comment: Just noticed the update, so basically now this LINQ fetches user's subscription , only those where the status is ==true and where the status is true it catches that subscription type. If I' got it right ? =)

Comment: Yes, you will get a user that meet the requested conditions that include the two level navigation properties

Comment: I'm getting an error saying: Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type bool and IEnumerable<Subscriptions> ?

Comment: RIght, wait a second

Comment: If you are expecting that all Subscription status are `true`, then use `All` extension method. If you need only those that meet the condition you will need to project your query

Comment: only 1 subscriptions is set to true at a time, he can't have more than 1 subscription set to true , should I use then "Any" with it like this ?

Comment: P.S. And what is the best / easiest way to access now subscription type. I managed to do it like this: _referredUser.Subscriptions.Select(x=>x.SubscriptionType.Price).FirstOrDefault() , is this the best way?

Comment: Use `Any` then. Yes from the user you are getting as result of that query, that could be a way to get the price from a `SubcriptionType`

Comment: amazing , thank you so much both guys, you've helped me alot. P.S. Just accepted ur answer =)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work...

```
var email = _all[i].Referred_email;
var _referredUser = ctx.Users
   .Include(x=>x.Subscriptions.Select(y=>y.SubscriptionType))
   .Select(x => new { User = x, Subscriptions = x.Subscriptions.Where(subscription => subscription.Status)})
   .Where(x => x.Subscriptions.Any())
   .Select(x => x.User)
   .FirstOrDefault(y => y.Email == email);
```

To include the child properties you can use `Select` in the include statement.
To only get the results where Subscriptions.Status is true you will need to do a separate query or do some Select() magic.

Comment: Shane, wow your solution looks neat and clean , hold on I'll try it out =)

Comment: Shane, how do I access now the subscriptiontype property inside subscriptions collection ?

Comment: I made an update as the Where() statement would not filter the child list (and wasnt valid syntax), it would just exclude Users entities that did not have any `Status == true`.  Give me a moment and ill write up a GroupBy that should do what you want.

Comment: Does this LINQ includes only those subscriptions where their status is ==true in table?

Comment: You 're executing two queries here, one to get all the users from your DB doing an inner join with subscriptions (if `SubstrictionType` is not a navigation property is not going to work). You're fetching all the user to memory to later filter and get one that meet the condition inside `FirstOrDefault` method, so IMHO this is not efficient way to get the expected result

Comment: @octavioccl is correct I should have caught this as well... No need for the ToList() here.

Comment: Yes, `ToList` is necessary in your solution due to array index

Comment: Guys, which solution is now more efficient? xD

Comment: @octavioccl Shane's solution doens't excludes those who have status == false , if I noticed good no?

Comment: Should be && y.Subscriptions.Where(y=>y.Status) , no ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, to address @octavioccl comments.. Still have not included the group by.  Hah, just noticed octavioccl also commented the same code below.  Sorry, apparently my brain is not working well this morning, I will let octavioccl  take it over from here.

Comment: @ShaneRay should the where statement include where statement which would exclude subscriptions whose status is set to false?

Comment: @ShaneRay No worries, one of the porpose of this site is to share knowledge

Comment: My code does not handle that.  The code that @octavioccl posted will not return a user entity if subscription status is set to false... is that what you want?  My understanding is that you still want the user, but only the subscriptions for that user with status == true.

Comment: @ShaneRay yes that's correct, user + only his subscription whos status is set to true and that subscriptions type..

Comment: I updated my code, its untested and after reading it again.. it is wrong.  I would generally use automapper projections for something like this. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions